# How can cache limit size of memory used?

Tags: java, caching

When cache allows you to specify max size of the cache in memory in megabytes. How does it enforce that it does not use more than that many megabytes?

For example in Java cache put() method could look like this:

```
put(Object key, Object value)
```

Is there an easy way to get object size of the value object by just from a reference? The only way I can think of is using reflection to traverse whole object structure recursively. But this should be slow.

Is there some different way to track memory impact in such cache?

Comment: Pick Java or C#. They are different languages with different runtimes and this will require 'magic' in each, excluding guestimations made off of traversals. If the cache is storing a serialized form, which is often the case when persisted, the size of the serialized form is trivially available after the serialization - but the serialization itself is a form of traversal.

Comment: Changed to Java. However they both have reflections.

Comment: Reflection only talks about the types. It's not possible for reflection to know if `byte[]` is 0 or one hundred million elements. Most serialization implementations use reflection and can still process objects 'very fast' (it is context relative). Shared and modifiable data is another complication of course..

Comment: Anyway the ultimate 'limit' of in-memory caches in Java/C# is often established with WeakReferences. When the process starts to run out of memory - and don't ask me how this relates to virtual memory or various system differences/configurations! - the WeakReference targets will be the first to go. The cache can use this to get 'automatic eviction on memory pressure' without setting an explicit size for itself.. of course this isn't the same as a strict size policy (but such usually applies to [persisted] caches hit after serialization).

Comment: There hmust be way to know size of elements at runtime. Otherwise serialization frameworks like xstream for Java would not work. For example it allows you to serialize mostly any object, which basically means that it has to go inside the object to find its dependencies.

Comment: Sure, they know the *serialized size*. And serialization implies traversal. You could manually serialize the objects and find the size of the resulting byte/text stream but there is no avoiding this traversal here. You could create a fake counting-only stream to avoid re-creating the traversal but note this only reflects the *serialized* size - which differs by serialization implementations - and it may differ from the actual memory usage. However, there might be some 'below language' approaches that can be used - I don't know what but there are some amazing JVM (and CLR) tricks.

Comment: Java provides an instrumentation agent to aid in calculating the runtime size. See [jamm](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm) and [allocation-instrumenter](https://github.com/google/allocation-instrumenter) for examples. This is not entirely accurate and each strategy has different tradeoffs.

Comment: @Ben Manes so looks like reflection is the answer?))

Comment: @Bohdan The shallow object size can be measured directly, while the deep size requires walking the object graph using reflection. That can be optimized using tools like [reflectasm](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/reflectasm) to only traverse the structure once reflectively.

Comment: OK, thanks, you could submit these comments as an answer, it answers this question.

Comment: Also that hack to inject handlers via allocation-instrumenter look pretty cool, I guess wrapping all objects with some CachedItem class and acting on it could be a way to keep track of all cache objects :)

Comment: @Bohdan You may also be interested in OpenJDK's [Java Object Layout](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) which is the most accurate but an immature project.

Answer (score 1):

The general way in many caches is to limit the count of objects. This ignores the fact that different objects might allocate different amounts of memory. However, on average, it is mostly doing okay.

In google guava you can assign an abstract weight to any object, which is used for eviction decisions. See: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained#Size-based_Eviction

EHCache implemented an automatic resource control which cares about object sizes. The engine behind this is a separate project on github: https://github.com/ehcache/sizeof, see also the blog post from Alex Saps: http://codespot.net/2012/01/04/measuring-java-object-sizes/

The is also a general library using the JVM instrumentation: https://github.com/jbellis/jamm. If I remember correctly EHCache sizeOf does implement different approaches, with jamm you are lost if instrumentation is not available on your JVM.

Comment: No, jamm provides multiple strategies (instrumentation, spec, unsafe).